# rails 3 best_in_place edit not working without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, edit-in-place

I took the comments code from Bernat's blog rails mini tutorial

I tried adding the edit in place functionality by using his best_in_place gem. For the most part it worked right

My code is deployed at 
http://falling-spring-3964.herokuapp.com/comments

You can look at the code here
https://github.com/sunnygill/commentsapp

Problem:

- I add a new comment. It shows up perfectly at the top of the page but the in place editing of the name does not work
- if i refresh the page then in pace editing works

Question:

How can i make the in place editing work without refreshing the page

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and my solution is add `$('.best_in_place').best_in_place();` to the `create.js.erb` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not wiring the in-line-edit javascript plugin to the newly created HTML element (that holds the name to be editable) after completing the ajax call. I tried to look at your source code on Github, but it looks outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller isn't responding to JSON for the update method. Pretty simple to fix: simply add something like the following to your update action.

```
def update
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user}
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
  ...
end
```